# Why the starting command for my Strapi project fails within the Docker environment

Tags: docker, strapi

I am trying to dockerize my strapi application, but the entrypoint command fails with:

```
error bootstrap function in plugin "documentation" failed
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
at Object.keys.reduce.required (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/services/Documentation.js:591:42)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at Object.generateMainComponent (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/services/Documentation.js:540:36)
at Object.generateResponseComponent (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/services/Documentation.js:1001:32)
at /usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/services/Documentation.js:165:53
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at Object.createDocumentationFile (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/services/Documentation.js:161:42)
at Object.checkIfAPIDocNeedsUpdate (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/services/Documentation.js:45:60)
at /usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/config/functions/bootstrap.js:64:43
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-documentation/config/functions/bootstrap.js:52:8)
at async Promise.all (index 2)
at async Strapi.runLifecyclesFunctions (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:443:5)
at async Strapi.load (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:379:5)
at async Strapi.start (/usr/srv/app/backend/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:196:9)
```

The project is starting without any issues on my mac. I've tried the solution from [here](https://forum.strapi.io/t/strapi-develop-error-bootstrap-function-in-plugin-documentation-failed-error-typeerror-strapi-admin-services-permission-actionprovider-registermany-is-not-a-function/8020) that implies removing the node_modules files and installing again, but without luck. I've also tried to start from different strapi images (with node-14,alphine etc). Do you guys have any idea about how I could solve this error or what's the cause of it? I am pretty new with the docker, maybe it's something wrong with the volumes?
The other services from my docker-compose are working just fine.

This is my docker-compose file

```
    version: "3.9"
 services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    environment:
      NEXT_API_LOCAL_DOMAIN: strapi
    volumes:
      - ./app-f:/srv/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - strapi
    networks:
      - strapi
  strapi:
    container_name: strapi

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: mysql
      DATABASE_HOST: mysql
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      DATABASE_NAME: strapi
      DATABASE_USERNAME: strapi
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: strapi
      DATABASE_SSL: "false"
     ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    networks:
      - strapi
  mysql_db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: strapi
      MYSQL_USER: strapi
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: strapi
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: strapi
    volumes:
      - ./.db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./backend/database_export/database_backup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database_backup.sql:ro
    networks:
      - strapi
networks:
  strapi:
    name: Strapi
    driver: bridge
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM strapi/strapi:3.6.8-node12

# Set Environment to Production Environment (Optional to include in Dockerfile)

ENV NODE_ENV staging

# Set up working directory that will be used to copy files/directories below :

WORKDIR /usr/srv/app/backend/
# Copy package.json to root directory inside Docker container of Strapi app

COPY ./backend/package.json .

RUN npm install
COPY ./backend/favicon.ico .

COPY ./backend/public/robots.txt ./public/

COPY ./backend/extensions/ ./extensions/


COPY ./backend/api/ ./api/

COPY ./backend/config/ ./config/
COPY ./backend/data/ ./data/
COPY ./backend/public/ ./public/
RUN npm run build --clean

ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]
```